# Tkinter testing with pywinauto

Tags: python, tkinter, gui-testing, pywinauto

I'm trying to do some Tkinter GUI testing with PyWinAuto. I have a simple app written in Tk, [which looks like this.](http://i.imgur.com/Grrio86.png)

The problem is - I can't get PyWinAuto to identify and use buttons / entries in my app.
I've tried 
`>>> app.Prototype.PrintControlIdentifiers()`
but it returns nothing or:

```
>>> app.Prototype.print_control_identifiers()
Control Identifiers:
TkChild - ''   (L308, T81, R1108, B681)
    '' '0' '1' 'TkChild' 'TkChild0' 'TkChild1'
Button - ''   (L763, T86, R878, B112)
    '2' 'Button' 'Button0' 'Button1'
Button - ''   (L613, T86, R728, B112)
    '3' 'Button2'
Button - ''   (L463, T86, R578, B112)
    '4' 'Button3'
Button - ''   (L313, T86, R428, B112)
    '5' 'Button4'
TkChild - ''   (L613, T171, R737, B198)
    '6' 'TkChild2'
TkChild - ''   (L463, T171, R587, B198)
    '7' 'TkChild3'
TkChild - ''   (L313, T171, R437, B198)
    '8' 'TkChild4'
Static - ''   (L613, T141, R949, B170)
    '9' 'Static' 'Static0' 'Static1'
Static - ''   (L463, T141, R799, B170)
    '10' 'Static2'
Static - ''   (L313, T141, R649, B170)
    '11' 'Static3'
```

The apps window name is Prototype (Tkinter title Prototype-GUI). I've also tried setting `_name` and `name` in widgets, like this:

```
param_range = Entry(wrapper, self.basicEntrySett, name="entryrange")
```

or:

```
param_range = Entry(wrapper, self.basicEntrySett, _name="entryrange")
```

but all it did was:

```
print param_range.winfo_name()
entryrange
```

and the print PrintControlIdentifiers output did not change. I would like to name them in a human-readable way.

Comment: Not sure if it will help you in this case or not, but look into [Swapy](https://code.google.com/p/swapy/).  It took a lot of the confusion and frustration out of PyWinAuto for me.

Comment: Dont know much about Tkinter. I see that you have set the name property of the control. Is it possible to set the text property instead? If not then you can do something like param_range = app.Prototype.Button0 & then param_range.click(). Just an example for using meaningful names.

Comment: @Jkdc well, it is easier to handle, but ID's of widgets sometimes change... and I have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a bit on this and found a **workaround**. This may not be considered as answer but helped me a lot to automate GUI testing of a python (Tkinter based) application.

**So, here is what I have learnt so far:**

The name property provided in the Tk widget object is just for reference and not an actual name used for the windows components.

After having a closer look to understand the behaviour naming.
If the application is loaded as `backend="win32"`, there are three types of elements I could find for my application `TkChild`, `Button`, and `Static`.

If the application is loaded as `backend="uia"`, there are three types of elements I could find for my application `Pane`, `Button`, and `Image`.

Here I used `uia`, now I am not sure if win32 should be used. But `uia` worked for me, hence, I kept going.

**The Workaround**

I have created the a list of names of widget objects used in my applications.
Now the rule of this list is whenever a new widget is added its added at index 0. The existing widgets are pushed down the list. e.g. If the application has a window with a tk.Frame and the the frame contains one text field and two buttons, here is how I can access this from `pywinauto`

```
pane_list = ["MyTxtInput", "", "MyFrame"]
button_list = ["MySecondButton", "","MyFirstButton"]
      
def update_text(main_window, text_box_name, text):
    index = pane_list.index[text_box_name]
    pane_id = "Pane{}".format(str(index))
    text_box = main_window[pane_id]
    text_box.type_keys(text)
    
def click_button(main_window, button_name):
    index = button_list.index[button_name]
    button_id = "Button{}".format(str(index))
    button = main_window[button_id]
    button.click_input()

# Here is how to use this
def test_my_app()
    app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="My Application")
    main_window = app.window(title="My Application")
    main_window.dump_tree()
    # Update text in the input
    update_text(main_window, "MyTxtInput", "This is added in the text input")
    # click button
    click_button(main_window, "MyFirstButton")
```

Now, if your application layout is dynamic can you are adding another frame with two buttons, the list will look like something below.

```
pane_list = ["NewFrame", "", "MyTxtInput", "MyFrame"]
button_list = ["NewFrame_SecondButton", "", "NewFrame_FirstButton", "MySecondButton", "MyFirstButton"]
```

The element at the index 1 is set to blank in the above lists, this is because, I have found the 0 and first element always same.

> Note: I used [SWAPY](https://github.com/pywinauto/swapy) tool to understand this behaviour. Though this tool is outdated and not maintained anymore, it helped me understand the behaviour.